# Install Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7

I have Windows 7 64 bit Enterprise edition installed. 
Which version of Visual Studio 2008 & Visual Studio 2010 (alongwith the Windows SDK for Win 7) should I install to create both Windows applications targetted to 64bit and 32 bit platforms?
Are there separate versions of Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2010 for 32bit and 64 bit OS ?
I see there are separate Windows SDKs & [debugging tools](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/install64bit.mspx) for 32 bit and 64 bit platforms. Which ones do I install ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there separate versions of Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2010 for 32bit and 64 bit OS ?

No.

The various SDKs etc can have x64 specific tools included, all you have to do is ensure you have selected those options from the features list during installation. If they are shipped as separate installs then you should be able to run both flavors - x86 and x64, then just use whichever one suits the app you are writing.

Comment: When you install Visual Studio all you have to do is select the options to include the 64-bit tools and compilers.

Comment: i installed the VS 2008 & 2010 Pro from DVD and the contents went to Program Files(x86)\ folder.....also I want to build target apps for a 32bit system from my 64 bit system. Are there are settings for that in VS? Also there's a windows_software_development_kit_for_windows_7_and_windows_server_2008_r2_x64 different from the 32 bit one

Comment: @iceman - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s(v=VS.100).aspx.  The procedure for C# is similar